# regex search and replace to remove all ID in sql export file using VIM

Tags: regex, wordpress, vim

I´m trying to import all media library from one wordpress to another and i´m following this post:

https://wp.timersys.com/importing-wordpress-attachments-media-library/

I need to replace in sql export file the Id values to `(`, I´m using VIM and i don´t know make the replacement search:

This is the point:

I did a regex search and replace to remove all ID from values. I used `\( ([0-9]+),` and replaced with just `(`

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression syntax used in that article is different from Vim's; that's why the replacement doesn't work. Unfortunately, there are many different regular expression dialects (basic, extended, Perl-compatible, and Vim even has several different "magic" modes). One solution is to switch to "very magic" mode via `\v`; then, the syntax matches (read `:help /\v` for more details):

```
:%s/\v\( ([0-9]+),/(/
```

Or, you convert the syntax to Vim's default: `\(` is used for grouping, `(` is a literal parenthesis, and `\+` is the multiplier:

```
:%s/( \([0-9]\+\),/(/
```

Actually, the grouping via `(...)` isn't necessary here, and Vim has `\d` instead of `[0-9]`:

```
:%s/( \d\+,/(/
```